# Show that $\mu(\Omega(T))=1$ for all $\mu\in M(X,T)$.

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, proof-verification

Let $X$ be a compact metrisable space, $\mathcal{B}(X)$ the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra, $M(X,T)$ the space of all probability measures on $(X,\mathcal{B}(X))$ which are preserved by $T$ and $\Omega(T)$ the non-wandering set.

> > **Definition** Let $T\colon X\to X$ be continuous. A point $x$ is called *wandering* for $T$ if there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that the sets $T^{-n}U, n\ge 0$, are mutually disjoint. The *non-wandering set for T*, $\Omega(T)$, consists of all the points that are not wandering for $T$.

**Task** Show that for every $\mu\in M(X,T)$, we have $\mu(\Omega(T))=1$.

Proof: Let $\left\{U_n\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a base of the topology $\tau$ on $X$. Then, $\Omega(T)^C$ is the union of those $U_n$ such that $T^{-m}U_n, m\ge 0$ are pairwise disjoint. Such a set $U_n$ must have measure $0$ for any invariant measure $\mu$, since suppose $c:=\mu(U_n)>0$, then $\mu(T^{-m}U_n)=c$ for all $m\ge 1$ and
$$
\mu(\bigcup_{m\ge 0}T^{-m}U_n)=\sum_{m\ge 0}\mu(T^{-m}U_n)=\sum_{m\ge 0}c=\infty
$$
what is not possible since $\mu$ is a probability measure. Hence $c=0$ and
$$
\mu(\Omega(T)^C)\leq 0\implies \mu(\Omega(T)^C)=0\implies \mu(\Omega(T)=1.
$$

**Is my proof okay?**

By the way: Is it really necessary that $X$ is metrisable?

Comment: Your proof is okay, and you only used the fact that the topology is second countable - that is -- it has a countable base.